# Trying to do a git checkout from a PHP script

Tags: php, git, nginx, ssh

I made a small php webhook that executes git command to checkout the code from a remote repository in a detached worktree.

I got this:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

I then changed the ownership of the .git directory to www-data to ensure that it gets written by the PHP script. I did this because when I executed whoami from browser, I got www-data. But now I always get:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:29:"Host key verification failed.";i:1;s:45:"fatal: Could not create www/.ssh directory.";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:51:"Please make sure you have the correct access rights";i:4;s:26:"and the repository exists.";}
```

Now for this, I opened up /etc/passwd and found that the directory for user `www-data` is set to /`var/www`. So I created a `/var/www/.ssh` using root and did `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.ssh`

In the newly created .ssh directory I did a ssh-keygen, copied the public key and added to my bitbucket account.

I again tried to execute the php script but i got the same error. `'Host key verification failed'`

Any takers? I am using nginx with php-fpm

I tried following this: https://serverfault.com/questions/362012/running-git-pull-from-a-php-script
but this is of no use. I am unable to even login as a new user. So a fresh approach to this may help.

Comment: and how does that comment help?

Comment: you can directly use username and password too if the script is for personal use.

Comment: Make sure only `www-data` has rights on directory `/var/www/.ssh` and the keys in it. The files `config` and `known_hosts` can be public readable though.

Comment: yes they are correct!

Comment: Did you do the ssh-keygen as www-data? Did you try to connect to the server from command line? 'sudo -u www-data ssh user@server'?